# Google App Engine/netbeans new web app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new here. I already search for the solutions to my problem but i cant find one. So y problem is when I'm creating new Web Application, and then i already choose the Google App Engine. Whenever i click Next, nothing happens. But there is an error sign that appears on the bottom-right part of the IDE.

### This is the content of messages.txt (log)

```
    >Log Session: Saturday, November 17, 2012 3:53:54 PM CST
    >System Info: 
      Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 (Build 201210100934) (#a183c5e41a19)
      Operating System        = Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86
      Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_05; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.1-b03; Oracle Corporation
      Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_05-b05
      Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre
      System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); Cp1252
      Home Directory          = C:\Users\MATT
      Current Directory       = C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1
      User Directory          = C:\Users\MATT\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1
      Cache Directory         = C:\Users\MATT\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.2.1
      Installation            = C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\ide
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\java
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\apisupport
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\webcommon
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\websvccommon
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\enterprise
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\profiler
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\harness
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\javafx
                                C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform
      Boot & Ext. Classpath   = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program      Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\classes;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\comm.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\jmf.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\sound.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
      Application Classpath   = C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\boot_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\boot_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\boot_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\boot_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program 

Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\lib\tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\core.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\core_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\core_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\core_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\core_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\org-netbeans-upgrader.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\core_nb.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\core_nb_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\core_nb_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\core_nb_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\core_nb_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.2.1\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar
```

---

i deleted some parts because of the character limit.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

this might be a problem.

```
Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre
```

see if you can change it to point to jdk instead of jre ?

```
Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
```